Failed to enable unit: Unit file p11-kit-client.service does not exist
I followed this tutorial pkcs11 remoting on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (https://p11-glue.github.io/p11-glue/p11-kit/manual/remoting.html)
and got the error when enable p11-kit-client.service.
systemctl --user enable p11-kit-client.service
Failed to enable unit: Unit file p11-kit-client.service does not exist.

I did create some tokens by softhsm modules, then
 run p11-kit server --provider /usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so ..., and export P11_KIT_SERVER_ADDRESS, P11_KIT_SERVER_PID but the unix socket /run/user/1001/p11-kit/ has size 0.

@guiverc I mean I executed them on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

You are aware if your system still reports itself as 22.04.4 that is likely a key indicator that you've not been applying security fixes for some time (or have security issues that should be explored), and I'll suggest exploring that if security matters to you. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/09/13/ubuntu-22-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 22.04.5, but installed systems upgraded & reported themselves as 22.04.5 weeks before that date (ISO release was delayed)
